# How to use iloc in an if condition for a single cell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given below is a snippet of my code. How can I check if the value of the cell [0, 'customer_state'] in my pandas dataframe (df) is the same as the string 'SP' ? I get a syntax error despite the fact that both are the same datatype.

[image]

Comment: You are missing a colon at the end of the if statement.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I just started coding in alternatively in different languages so that's probably why I got confused. The code works properly now. I am sorry for wasting your time.